# Show that there is exactly one ring homomorphism $(\Bbb{Z}/3\Bbb{Z})\times(\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z})\to\Bbb{Z}/12\Bbb{Z}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

The set $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})$ is a ring with the component-wise addition and multiplication, the zero element $([0], [0])$ and the one element $([1], [1])$. I have to show that there is exactly one ring homomorphism $(\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}) \to \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$. Then I have to show that this ring homomorphism is also an isomorphism.

Best regards

Comment: The isomorphism follows from the Chinese remainder theorem. You can do the proof with this example. What is $f(1)=f([1],[1])$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the *Chinese Remainder theorem*.

$f(x,y)=-3x+4y$ is the rule for the isomorphism.

Now check that it's a surjective homomorphism (with necessarily trivial kernel).

Thus, $(1,1)$ has order $12$, and generates $\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_4$, which is cyclic.

This means that any ring homomorphism is determined by the image of $(1,1)$.

But the image has to be$1$ (assuming you require this).

Comment: Why did you change your answer?

Comment: Well, it occurred to me that the uniqueness followed from the fact that $(1,1)$ is a generator a little more easily.